# Magento 2 visual swatch doesn't show if I use Price slider

Tags: magento2, sidebar

I'm using magento 2 and I've installed a module for the price slider , is the emizentech price slider , but when I enable it , the visual swatch from the sidebar disappear , but not from the product listing or product page , just from the sidebar , how can I get them having also the price slider ? I've tryed to compare the files before and after enableing the module , and I've made some changes , but still not showing up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was an conflict with Magento_Swatches module 
it disables the Magento_Swatches plugin for the LayeredNavigation
This issue has been resolved in latest commits

Kindly use the latest updates form EmizenTech's GIT Repo for Price Slider

https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-price-slider