# Magento 2 code to add block into phtml file

Tags: magento2, blocks

I'm using Magento 2 and I want to add block to all my category pages , by directly writing it into the code in the `app/design/frontend/Venustheme/yume/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` page , there is any way to call the block there, and not through the admin panel?

Comment: The same question I found on stackoverflow. Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594339/inserting-blocks-into-custom-places-in-magento2/36657719#36657719

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your theme folder, add a `Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` layout file. Load your block into the parent block with the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <block name="your.cms.block" as="something" class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">[put your block ID here]</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In your `list.phtml` simply call `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('something') ?>`. Of course you should name your blocks differently, but I hope you got the general idea.

Comment: Hi , this works fine , thank you very much ! but when I print my block , it appears inside the <li></li> , here is my code .. what I'm doying wrong  ? <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                <?php
                    $contator++;
                    if($contator==3){
                        echo $block->getChildHtml('category-middlemsg');
                    }
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: What is it? Anyway, you should totally avoid using `count()` inside a `foreach` loop, it is a well-known performance killer. Assign that value to a variable **before** the loop and compare the variable instead.

Comment: is the counter I did before the loop , so I can count the products , as I want to print my block after 3 products , now is printing the block inside the <li></li> , I want to print it outside..

Comment: Edit your question and post your code for us to understand, or open a new question maybe.

Comment: Ok, I see what you want to do... unfortunately the standard template is quite poorly written, so you'll either have to write your own or stick to this `<li></li>`. Everything inside an ordered list should be wrapped inside a `<li>` anyway, I guess it's not so bad if you stick to that

Comment: I want to stick it yes to the <li></li> , is just that now it does that <li>here</li> , I just want to print it <li></li>here

Comment: Do something like this `<?php if ($iterator === 6) echo '</li><li class="item product product-item">' . $block->getChildHtml('something') ?>`

Comment: thank you very much @fmrng , that solved my issue ! I have got another big issue I can't really solve.. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114617/magento-2-visual-swatch-doesnt-show-if-i-use-price-slider  what do you think about ?

Comment: Hi @fmrng, and what about if I would like to add a block in category page without printing `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('something') ?>` in my `list.phtml` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the layout xml to add a block instead of a template file.

In your module, add a file *view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml.*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="whatever.container.i.want.to.reference">
            <block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\BlockClass" name="my.block.name" template="Namespace_Modulename::path/to/template/file.phtml" />
            </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Depending on the type of block you are creating, you don't always need a template file.

Comment: Is just a block with a div as a content , is just that everytime I will need to edit it , I want to edit the block throught the adminpanel - content - blocks - my block , that's why I need a way to call it directly incode , also because I want to put it after 6 products have been listed , so into my list.phtml , I made a counter , and after the first 6 products are listed , I want to add my block , so I need a way to call it directly in code , the code you posted is ok , but I can't just put it after 6 products.. I don't know if I explained myself well..